# ESXi: auto assign vnc port for each machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vnc, esxi

I need to take remote console of VM running on ESXi host. I need to take VNC for that purpose. To this to happen I need to assign TCP Port to each VM manually or programmatically (of course, by editing VMX file) using settings given below.

```
remotedisplay.vnc.port="5900"
remotedisplay.vnc.enabled="true"
remotedisplay.vnc.password = "yourpassword"
```

Is there any mechanism (preferrably psphere API) that I can tell ESX to assign port automatically for all machine or single machine for that matter?

Thanks & Regards,
Ganesh

PS. I'm using Ubuntu 14 and want to connect VMs via browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did to get it working using pysphere

```
>>> from pysphere import VIServer
>>> s = VIServer()
>>> s.connect('10.11.100.220', 'root', 'password')
>>> vm = s.get_vm_by_name("VMNAME")
>>> settings = {'remotedisplay.vnc.port': '8949', 'remotedisplay.vnc.enabled' : 'true'}
>>> vm.set_extra_config(settings)
>>> s.disconnect()
```

Comment: FYI the pysphere API has been deprecated in favor of vmware's official https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer I know both PySphere and pSphere have stopped support. I have already evaluated PyVMOMI but not much examples are there regarding such tasks. Of course, except listing out VMs, creating VMs etc. For other tasks we've to dig the API and find out what to do. They should give some more examples. There is repository for PyVMOMI but it's not that useful .

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is ssh into the esx server and append the vmx file with those properties.

```
echo -e "RemoteDisplay.vnc.enabled = true\nRemoteDisplay.vnc.port = 5900\nRemoteDisplay.vnc.password = \"yourpassword\"" >> /vmfs/volumes/YOURDATASTORE/YOURVMNAME/YOURVMNAME.vmx
```

or in one command

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh root@10.54.140.145 "echo -e \"RemoteDisplay.vnc.enabled = true\nRemoteDisplay.vnc.port = 5900\nRemoteDisplay.vnc.password = \"yourpassword\"\" >> /vmfs/volumes/YOURDATASTORE/YOURVMNAME/YOURVMNAME.vmx"
```

If that's not your vmx path, you can also dynamically get it using

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep VMNAME | awk '{print $4}'
```

or all in one line

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh root@10.54.140.145 "echo -e \"RemoteDisplay.vnc.enabled = true\nRemoteDisplay.vnc.port = 5900\nRemoteDisplay.vnc.password = \"yourpassword\"\" >> $(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep VMNAME | head -1 | awk '{print $4}')"
```

Comment: When you write to VMX file, your machine needs to be in powered off state.

Comment: You can also power down the VM before modifying the VMX file using `vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off $( vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep 'VMNAME' | awk '{print $1}' )`. Then modify the VMX and use `vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on` to bring it back up with VNC enabled.

Comment: I can't power off the machine :(

Comment: If you get the VMID using `vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms` and then pass that ID to `vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off VIMID` then it should power off correctly.

Comment: thing is I don't want to power off machine. Just to change one setting. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean. Yes, the python API is awesome how it allows you to modify the VM settings while the VM is still up. When I read "can't" I think, "physically unable to". What you meant to say was "I would rather not power off the machine, that's why I prefer to use the python API." :)

Comment: yeah, it makes life easier :)